# "SameSite=none" does not work with iframe

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, samesite

After upgrade to **Chrome Version 80.0.3987.132** cookies are not sent to the iframe request. On the Network tab (Chrome Dev tools), I do not see cookies for my requests.

After turning on the option "show filtered out requests cookies" I sees my cookies marked **"This cookies was not sent due to user preferences."**

The header for the cookie set:

```
set-cookie: token=jf23HaUI91Bd8L1chHq; expires=Wed, 18-Mar-2020 16:01:59 GMT; Max-Age=1799; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; domain=.example-domain.com; HttpOnly
```

When I open an iframe on the same domain everything works fine, but if it is a third-party domain via http or https, cookies will not work.

Has anyone come across this or know how to fix it?

Comment: Is this over https? Over http I don't think this will work. You have the secure flag in your header, requiring a secure connection

Comment: have the similar problem with: https + samesite=none;secure + iframe. cookies are not passed. did u find the solution @mikolay-bet

Comment: it's been awhile no answer yet !

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Deselect **Block third-party cookies** on `chrome://settings/content/cookies`

Comment: This is not a solution, you can't have all your users disable third-party cookie blocking !

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ensure that SameSite flag is always set to None for those cookies. If it's initially set to Lax, and then you try to make it None, it may not work. 
Also, you should ensure that Secure flag is always set to true for SameSite=None cookies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iframe with https, sanbox your iframe to get cookies working:

```
referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-storage-access-by-user-activation allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation"
allow="encrypted-media; fullscreen; oversized-images; picture-in-picture; sync-xhr; geolocation;"
allowpaymentrequest="true"
allowpopups
allowfullscreen
```

Not sure what else you will need.

And you also you or not need your service in the iframe to set cookies with extra params

```
Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=none
```

Answer (score -2):

It works for me, setting cookie via PHP;
This is a HACK for php  < 7.3  (!)

session_set_cookie_params(3600*24, '/;SameSite=None', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], true);

(secure = true is important)

Answer (score -2):

In case of hosting in IIS you can add below configurations in web.config to avoid adding `SameSite=Lex` by browser

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" **cookieless="UseCookies" cookieSameSite="None"** timeout="20"/>
```